# Efficient way to count number of int and float in string using Python

Tags: python, regex

Is there any efficient way to find count of int and float in string, without using two different list comprehension

```
st = '2.00 00 DBEL 215 Frox Lyxo 2.000 2.00'

reg = r'\d+(?:\.\d*)?'

out = re.compile(reg).findall(st)

# output as  ['2.00', '00', '215', '2.000', '2.00']

int_in_string = len([i for i in out if isinstance(eval(str(i)), int)])
fl_in_string = len([i for i in out if isinstance(eval(str(i)), float)])

print('no of int : ', int_in_string, 'no of float : ', fl_in_string)
```

Comment: yes; by using a `for`-loop.

Comment: And the usage of `eval` is by no means recommended as it is not *safe*.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I know but without eval it does not match string is int or float.

Comment: Easiest way is just to use a for-loop.

Comment: Don't use \d use [0123456789] instead

Comment: You don't need to use `eval` to do that.

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-float) will help you, you just have to implement another twin function for int. It is based on [handling exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the following:

```
st = '2.00 00 DBEL 215 Frox Lyxo 2.000 2.00'

floats, ints = 0, 0
for word in st.split():
    try:
        int(word)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            float(word)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            floats += 1
    else:
        ints += 1

print('no of int : ', ints, 'no of float : ', floats)  # no of int :  2 no of float :  3
```

---

My code takes a different approach. `regex` is not used. The string is `split` on whitespace and the individual words are cast to `float` and `int` inside `try`-blocks. If the tries are successful (`else`-part of the block), a counter is increased.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to actually save the numbers again on `int_in_string` and `fl_in_string`, so you could use two simple counters

```
int_in_string = 0
fl_in_string   = 0
for i in out:
    if isinstance(eval(str(i)), int):
        int_in_string += 1
    elif isinstance(eval(str(i)), float):
        fl_in_string += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your ints follow the pattern `\d+` and all your floats follow the pattern `\d+\.\d+`, you can count them as follows

```
>>> num_ints = sum(1 for _ in re.finditer(r'(?<=\W)\d+(?=\W)', st))
>>> num_floats = sum(1 for _ in re.finditer(r'(?<=\W)\d+\.\d+(?=\W)', st))
>>> print (num_ints, num_floats)
6 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming regex is NOT a must.

```
st = '2.00 00 DBEL 215 Frox Lyxo 2.000 2.00'
s = [i.isdigit() for i in st.split(' ') if not(i.isalpha())]
print('no of int : ', s.count(True), 'no of float : ', s.count(False))
```